# Including same jar library in application module and library module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Android application which has a main application module and a library module. Both the main application module and library module is dependent on an external jar library. I get the following error while building

> Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
>       Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define

I understand that this is caused by including same jar twice. Is there anything I can do without restructuring the project to use jar only once.

Comment: What's the jar? Can you not find a Maven/Gradle  dependency for it?

Comment: It it a proprietary jar. I don't think it is published in Maven. How will finding dependency help in this case?

Comment: Because gradlew handles duplicate files in dependencies better than squashing jar files

Comment: I am very new to gradle build system or infact any build system other than make. The functionality I am using from the jar is same for both application module and library module. I am not sure if I can exclude anything.

Comment: Alright. I think the answer below should work, if not, adding all your `build.gradle` files and `settings.gradle`

Comment: you can solve your problem by making the jar a compile-only dependency for the lib and both compile and runtime dependency for the app

Comment: you say you don't want to restructure your project, but we don't know how it is structured in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

This is happening because your app depends on the library module. Because the library module already has the jar dependency then you get this error.

I will explain further. You have `Module-A`, `Module-B`, and `Module-C`.

`Module-B` depends on `Module-C`.

`Module-A` depends on `Module-B` and `Module-C`.

But since `Module-B` already depends on `Module-C` you get the problem.

### Solution

Make the library module the only dependent of the jar.

In other words, make `Module-A` depend on `Module-B` and no need to make it depend on `Module-C`.

Comment: Why the down vote? I believe my answer is correct. If it is not please point it out and I will gladly delete it. Thank you!

Comment: I din't down vote. Your solution is not wrong but it did not answer my question. I restructured my app to remove the jar dependency from the main module.  But I expected that there is some way that a jar would work similar to how .so or a .dll would work. Like I have libsqlite.so depending on libc.so and libstagefright.so depending on libc.so. Both libsqlite.so and libstagefright.so can be linked to my main application. What I had is a similar situation in java.

Comment: @digitizedx what part of your question did I miss?

Comment: I will explain my requirement. I have a logger.jar which provides logging services. My aar and main module both needs the logger. If I include it in both build.gradles I get dex error during final application creation. How do I solve this

Comment: @digitizedx I updated my answer to explain in more detail. It is still the same solution. Best of luck!

Comment: I finally did exactly this. But I did it  before asking this. But is there no other solution?